# jasper remove image grouped variable

Tags: image, jasper-reports

The example of grouped report:

[image: example of grouped report]

The image above is the situation where the an product-image is present. This a desired situation.

The problem arises when there is no product-image present. In this case I get the generic image placeholder ( see pic. 2 ).

The design view of the lines document:
[image: design view of the lines document]

The generic image is unwanted and I want it removed, but I can't get the print-when-expression to work. Actually I want to remove the entire space of the image placeholder so that the description of the product is more or less connected to the grey bar on top.

I am trying to do the print-when-expression based on the variable 'productImageGroup'

definition of productImageGroup:

```
<variable name="productImageGroup" class="java.lang.String" resetType="Group" resetGroup="productCode">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{setting.reportDir} + "users/" + $F{user} + "/" + $F{k_product_id}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
```

Thanks for helping out. I could post some of the xml data, but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to remove the image in the is to use a `printWhenExpression` on the band, something like

```
<groupHeader>
    <band height="50">
      <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new java.io.File($V{productImageGroup}.exists())]]></printWhenExpression>           
   </band>
</groupHeader>
```

**Note**: if you like to keep the text in `groupHeader`, you will need to create another group for this